# Chemistry write-ups in LaTex - is it worth drawing figures in LaTex?

Tags: software

Being an undergraduate chemistry student I have to write a significant amount of hand-ins e.g. lab reports. Up until now I've been using LaTex with [`mhchem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) for equations and [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for numbers/units, but I've not invested the time and effort in learning other, more complicated chemistry related packages. This means, that I usually draw mechanisms with ChemDraw and other figures with image editors.

So my question is: which packages is it worth spending the time on learning (and using)?

E.g. [`chemfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) for complicated reaction schemes, [`modiagram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/modiagram) for molecular orbital diagrams, [`bpchem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bpchem) for IUPAC names and common idioms, etc.

Comment: This is a great question, but it's unfortunately a poor fit for the Q&A side of the site. Please raise it in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table)! I suspect there will be opinions there, on the matter.

Comment: [Permalink to head of chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44865405#44865405)